# Tuple keeps crashing on sql stored procedure because it has too many arguments specified

Tags: c#, tuples

In c# asp.net I have a function tuple where I give the Username and Password with. The function checks if it's in a sqldatabase using a stored procedure. But if I call the function tuple twice, first to get the 1st value, and next the 2nd value I get an error that the Procedure has too many arguments specified. I am just new in the world of function tuple, thanks alot!

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginGebruikersNaam = txtGebruikersNaam.Text;
        LoginWachtwoord = txtWachtwoord.Text;
        lblMessage.Text = (B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord)).Item1;
        Ingelogd = (B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord)).Item2;

    }

public Tuple<string, bool> Inloggen(string LoginGebruikersNaam, string LoginWachtwoord)
    {
        bool Ingelogd = false;
        string Message = String.Empty;
        string Voornaam = String.Empty, Naam = String.Empty;
        _LoginGebruikersNaam = LoginGebruikersNaam;
        _LoginWachtwoord = LoginWachtwoord;

        cmdInloggen.Connection = cnn;
        cmdInloggen.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdInloggen.CommandText = "SPInloggen";
        cmdInloggen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginGebruikersNaam", _LoginGebruikersNaam);
        cmdInloggen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginWachtwoord", _LoginWachtwoord);

        cnn.Open();
        drInloggen = cmdInloggen.ExecuteReader();
        while (drInloggen.Read())
        {
            Voornaam = drInloggen[0].ToString();
            Naam = drInloggen[1].ToString();
        }
        cnn.Close();

        if (Voornaam == String.Empty || Naam == String.Empty)
        {
            Message = "De logingegevens kloppen niet! Controleer de gegevens en probeer het opnieuw!";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "Welkom " + Voornaam + " " + Naam + "! U bent succesvol ingelogd.";
            Ingelogd = true;
        }


        return new Tuple<string, bool>(Message, Ingelogd);
    }
```

Comment: where is `cmdInloggen` declared and instantiated? it *looks* like you might be using it over and over, adding more and more parameters each time, no? (edit: I'm too scared to ask where `cnn` is declared and instantiated)

Comment: Don't reuse SQL objects (like `cmdInloggen`). It leads to predictable errors like these. Create new ones whenever you need them. (And consider not using [`AddWithValue`](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). And definitely consider not passing passwords in plaintext to the database, and certainly not storing them as such!)

Comment: or even better: use Dapper - it is your friend! `(var voornaam, var naam) = cnn.QuerySingleOrDefault<(string, string)>("SPInloggen", new { LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);` - et voila, all done

Comment: The problem is I only need to use the sql object cmdInloggen once to check the login data... but can I call the function once? for example (this gives you a idea but is not correct) lblmessage.text, Status = (B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord)).Item1, item2;

Comment: additional note: plain text passwords are a very bad idea - I hope they aren't stored as plain text in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a: you're calling the stored procedure twice...

once here:

```
lblMessage.Text = (B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord)).Item1;
```

and then again here:

```
Ingelogd = (B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord)).Item2;
```

b: you appear to be reusing a command object (not a good idea, frankly), and not clearing the parameters; so by calling it twice, the first time it'll have 2 parameters, and the second time it'll have 4.

So... don't do that!

Frankly, your ADO.NET code needs ... quite a bit of work; right now there's a *lot* of problems with it. I don't mean that negatively - ADO.NET is hard to get right, but ... *because* it is hard to get right, there are tools like "dapper" that will **really** help you, making it much easier to default to success, rather than failure. I strongly recommend using them.

Problems right now:

- reusing a command (casually)
- possible thread-safety on the command and connection
- an unclosed reader
- multiple `IDisposable` problems
- failure to consider `null` parameters (as opposed to `DBNull`)

etc

Comment: Hi Marc, thanks for your answer! Is there a way to get them both out by only calling it once?

Comment: @PieterPauwels yes.... `var tuple = B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord); lblMessage.Text = tuple.Item1; Ingelogd  = tuple.Item2;` - however, you might prefer "value tuples" if you're using a modern C# version - much easier to work with

Comment: Idealy what I needed! I am pritty young so I have a road to go, this helped me out!

Comment: @PieterPauwels I'm still very concerned about where `cnn` and `cmdInloggen` and `drInloggen` are declared - I worry that you're making some *very* bad choices there that could hurt you - so... if you have time, I'd love to see where they are defined

Comment: Surely, I appreciate the help!                                                                       'public class BusLayer
       { 
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(Global.cnnmySQL);
        SqlCommand cmdInloggen = new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataReader drInloggen;

        private string _LoginGebruikersNaam, _LoginWachtwoord;
        public Tuple<string, bool> Inloggen(string LoginGebruikersNaam, string LoginWachtwoord)
        {'

Comment: @PieterPauwels yeah, there's *really* no need to have a command or data-reader as fields - they are usually just locals in a method that touches the database; and if `Inloggen` takes the name/password as parameters, I'm not sure that they need to be fields too. The connection might as well be deferred to when you actually need it too, using a `using`. There's a lot to learn on data access, sadly - it is a big topic.

Comment: The datareader and sqlcommand is not needed indeed! The cnn is handy for my next connections, thanks for your time and help!

Comment: @PieterPauwels well, I could debate that topic all day, but if you're going to hold one because it is useful, then you are implicitly taking on the job of ensuring that you implement `IDisposable` in `B`, cascade-dispose the connection in `B.Dispose()`, and make sure that anything that uses `B` *also* ensures that `B` is disposed correctly. So: it *really* isn't a decision you want to take lightly.

Answer (score 1):

In your original code, you are calling `B.Inloggen` twice.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LoginGebruikersNaam = txtGebruikersNaam.Text;
    LoginWachtwoord = txtWachtwoord.Text;
    var response = B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord);
    lblMessage.Text = response.Item1;
    Ingelogd = response.Item2;
}

public Tuple<string, bool> Inloggen(string LoginGebruikersNaam, string LoginWachtwoord)
{
    bool Ingelogd = false;
    string Message = String.Empty, Voornaam = String.Empty, Naam = String.Empty;

    using(SqlCommand cmdInLoggen = new SqlCommand("SPInloggen", cnn))
    {
        cmdInloggen.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmdInloggen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginGebruikersNaam", _LoginGebruikersNaam);
        cmdInloggen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginWachtwoord", _LoginWachtwoord);

        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            using (var drInloggen = cmdInloggen.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (drInloggen.Read())
                {
                    Voornaam = drInloggen[0].ToString();
                    Naam = drInloggen[1].ToString();
                }

                if (Voornaam == String.Empty || Naam == String.Empty)
                {
                    Message = "De logingegevens kloppen niet! Controleer de gegevens en probeer het opnieuw!";
                }
                else
                {
                    Message = "Welkom " + Voornaam + " " + Naam + "! U bent succesvol ingelogd.";
                    Ingelogd = true;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Enforce the connection is closed even when exception is raised
            if (cnn.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) cnn.Close();
        }
    }

    return new Tuple<string, bool>(Message, Ingelogd);
}
```

Also, the SQL stored procedure is expected to return one record, so, I have removed the while loop.

Comment: thoughts: I'd love to see a `using` around `cmdInLoggen`, and `drInloggen` defined as a local, ideally *also* with a `using`; also, `_LoginGebruikersNaam` and `_LoginWachtwoord` serve no purpose (just use the parameters), and most of the other locals could be deferred

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have got answer why you are getting that error too many argument specified and do not need to call twice that function to get those two values. You can call once. 
Anyway I have also just modified your code with using block. To connect SQL and retrieve data you are using ADO .net but that is un managed code that does not manage by CLR.
For that I have used Using block, it implements IDisposable so we do not need explicitly dispose of the objects in code. Also we do not need to close the connection because once its out of scope of using block it automatic close the connection.

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoginGebruikersNaam = txtGebruikersNaam.Text;
        LoginWachtwoord = txtWachtwoord.Text;
        var tupleDetails = B.Inloggen(LoginGebruikersNaam, LoginWachtwoord);
        lblMessage.Text = tupleDetails.Item1;
        Ingelogd = tupleDetails.Item2;

    }
```

public Tuple Inloggen(string LoginGebruikersNaam, string LoginWachtwoord)
        {

```
        bool Ingelogd = false;
        string Message = String.Empty;
        string Voornaam = String.Empty, Naam = String.Empty;
        var _LoginGebruikersNaam = LoginGebruikersNaam;
        var _LoginWachtwoord = LoginWachtwoord;
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(cnn))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmdInloggen = new SqlCommand("SPInloggen", sqlConnection))
                {
                    cmdInloggen.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdInloggen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginGebruikersNaam", _LoginGebruikersNaam);
                    cmdInloggen.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LoginWachtwoord", _LoginWachtwoord);

                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader drInloggen = cmdInloggen.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (drInloggen.Read())
                        {
                            Voornaam = drInloggen[0].ToString();
                            Naam = drInloggen[1].ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Message = ex.ToString();               
        }

        if (Voornaam == String.Empty || Naam == String.Empty)
        {
            Message = "De logingegevens kloppen niet! Controleer de gegevens en probeer het opnieuw!";
        }
        else
        {
            Message = "Welkom " + Voornaam + " " + Naam + "! U bent succesvol ingelogd.";
            Ingelogd = true;
        }


        return new Tuple<string, bool>(Message, Ingelogd);
    }
```